# Realtek Wifi Adapter: Super High Ping on Internet-Connected software (Discord, TF2, Portal 2, etc.)

Tags: wireless, realtek, ping

I have an HP Laptop with Kubuntu 16.10 dual-booting alongside Windows 10.

I just updated it from 16.04, and suddenly TF2, Discord, Portal 2, and other programs are experiencing fluctuating ping, from decent (20-50ms range) to downright horrible (430-500ms). I have tried updating the kernel to 4.10.5 (the latest stable release), but after rebooting it didn't do a single thing.

I have a Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter as my Wifi card.

When I ping my router:`

```
evan@evan-computer-a:~$ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.09 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=5.61 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.61 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=4.06 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=3.95 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=4.34 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=2.97 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=6.61 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=4.63 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=2.72 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=4.01 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=2.75 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=2.92 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=6.31 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=4.75 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=2.72 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=3.80 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=3.81 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=2.40 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=6.69 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19032ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.097/4.042/6.694/1.352 ms
```

When I ping Google:

```
evan@evan-computer-a:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.21.106) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=28.9 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=23.4 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=25.1 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=4 ttl=45 time=23.6 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=5 ttl=45 time=31.7 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=6 ttl=45 time=104 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=7 ttl=45 time=26.8 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=8 ttl=45 time=33.7 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=9 ttl=45 time=31.8 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=10 ttl=45 time=24.1 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=11 ttl=45 time=22.6 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=12 ttl=45 time=22.5 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=13 ttl=45 time=180 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=14 ttl=45 time=27.6 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=15 ttl=45 time=25.5 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=16 ttl=45 time=24.7 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=17 ttl=45 time=22.4 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=18 ttl=45 time=37.5 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=19 ttl=45 time=40.3 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f106.1e100.net (74.125.21.106): icmp_seq=20 ttl=45 time=27.5 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 20 received, 0% packet loss, time 19031ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.430/39.290/180.588/36.788 ms
```

As you can see, there is no packet loss on both of them, and the ping is completely fine, except on a few places in the Google ping.

I have tried looking at many other sites to fix the problem, none has worked. Laptop power management is off (my laptop is connected directly to power anyways - there isn't a battery in it). The kernel is the most up-to-date as it can be (without being unstable). I have absolutely no idea why my ping on TF2, Discord, and other programs is so high and fluctuating so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed my ping:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git dkms
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd ~/rtlwifi_new
make
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188ee
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee
```

The first modprobe command will disconnect your computer to the internet, and the second will reconnect it. After I completed the commands, I rebooted my system and everything was fixed & working fine.

This will also work for most other Realtek adapters, all you do is put your model in place of "rtl8188ee". (The files that were downloaded have those other models included as well.)